# Postgresql database superuser

Tags: postgresql, permissions, sql-grant

I am attempting to secure a database made up of multiple schemas as follows:-

```
-public
-foo
-bar
-foobar
```

I want to create a user who can access any schema for read, can create tables in bar and can inert/update/delete in foo,bar and foobar

I would prefer to create user as a database superuser and then remove privileges as required.

I thought:-

```
CREATE USER test_superuser;
GRANT ALL on DATABASE test to test_superuser;
```

Would do this, but after these commands test_superuser cannot access the schema.

How can I create a user that has the permissions of postgres superuser but only on a named database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out this needed a lot of tinkering to achieve:-

```
     CREATE ROLE test_database_superuser
     NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL '2020-03-06 00:00:00';


    CREATE ROLE test_user LOGIN
      ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md52b250919b406b707999fffb2b9f673fb'
      NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL '2020-03-06 00:00:00';

    GRANT test_database_superuser TO test_user;

    --DATABASE LEVEL PRIVELEGES
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test to test_database_superuser;

    --SCHEMA LEVEL
    GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA bar TO GROUP test_database_superuser;
    GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA foo TO GROUP test_database_superuser;
    GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA foobar TO GROUP test_database_superuser;

    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA foo TO GROUP test_database_superuser;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA foo TO GROUP test_database_superuser;

    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA bar TO GROUP test_database_superuser;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA bar TO GROUP test_database_superuser;

    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA foobar TO GROUP test_database_superuser;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA foobar TO GROUP test_database_superuser;


    --PUBLIC
    GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO GROUP test_database_superuser;
```

Comment: Why did you need to grant ALL PRIVILEGES on tables/seqs in schema BAR after GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA ?

Answer (score 1):

Allow [usage of the schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-grant.html)

```
GRANT { { CREATE | USAGE } [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON SCHEMA schema_name [, ...]
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

Something like:

```
 GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA your_schame TO test_superuser;
```

By the way, this is not a "super user", just a user with lots of permissions...

Comment: There are a lot of schemas in the database, can it really not be done at the database level

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$ sudo su - postgres
postgres@derrick:~$ createuser -P
Enter name of role to add: web_app
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) n
postgres@derrick:~$

postgres@derrick:~$ createdb --owner web_app dbTest
postgres@derrick:~$ logout
```

Comment: This does not answer the specific permissions requested above. It simply gives ownership to user web_app

Comment: In hindsight you are correct. I do have ask, if you have time. What is the scenario for such a complicated setup? How are the databases accessed, via the web?

Comment: It is for a web facing app. I always give the minimum access required rather than the max, these requirements represent the base set.